# What are the default VST and AU locations in Snow Leopard when installing audio programs?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard

I would like to know the default location where Snow Leopard stores VSTs and AUs (audio units or virtual instruments).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all users:

- /Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/Components for Audio Units
- /Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/VST for VST plugins

For just you:

- ~/Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/Components for Audio Units
- ~/Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/VST for VST plugins